# Не работает else(((

Tags: javascript

Есть скрипт, который выборочно выводит свойство объекта через **prompt**.
По задумке, если пользователь ведет другое значение, которого нет в объекте, то должно выводиться сообщение **"Введите age или name"**, но вместо него выходит значение **undefined**

В каком месте я ошибся?

```js
let border = prompt('Что хотите узнать?' , '');

let user ={
name: 'Domik',
age: 99, 
};

if (border == border){
alert(user[border]);
}

else{
alert('Введите age или name'); 
}
```

Comment: а что `if (border == border)` это значит?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ошибка здесь:

```
if (border == border)
```

Эта конструкция бессмысленная. Вы проверяете значение переменной с самой собой.

---

Как вариант: брать имена ключей и проверять наличие имени этого ключа в массиве. Если есть - то выводить значение по ключу, в ином случае - ошибку.

```js
let border = prompt('Что хотите узнать?', '');

let user = {
  name: 'Domik',
  age: 99,
};

let objectPropertyKeys = Object.keys(user);
let alertText = objectPropertyKeys.includes(border) ? user[border] : `Введите одно из значений: ${objectPropertyKeys.join(', ')}`;

alert(alertText);
```

Comment: Благодарю, если Вас это не затруднит, то не могли бы Вы пожалуйста дать ссылку на статью, где подробно написано об этом.

Comment: Об этом - о чём?))

Comment: Об свойстве "Object" она в Object.keys(user);

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys  - конкретно о ключах и в целом: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object  - список методов

Comment: Ваш первый вариант был короче, в чем его разница со вторым вариантом)?

Comment: Наоборот, первый вариант длиннее. Я избавился от лишних переменных, строк и  условий.  из 7 строк сделал две (не считая пустую строку для отделения кода). На производительность не влияет, смысл один и тот же. Просто сделан оптимизированней в плане читаемости. Ну плюс минус. Но можно использовать и первый вариант, если хочется